# Neverending loop in C++, that compares two char's

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, while-loop, char

I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
     char str1[] = "abc123";
     char str2[] = "abc123";
     do
     {
          std::cout << "String: ";
          std::cin >> str2;
     } while (str1 != str2);
     std::cout << "str1 is equal to str2, press any key to quit.\n";
     _getch();
     return 0;
}
```

The program should end when str1 is equal to str2, and str2 is a value set by the user. The problem is, even if I type the same value as str1, it keeps looping, it doesn't matter if I put the same contents as in str1 or not.

Comment: Cause you are comparing addresses. Try to display what `str1` and `str2` is.

Comment: Neither do I. Most questions receive downvotes for no reason, if you already know the answer doesn't mean someone else should too.

Comment: lol char arrays in a question tagged as C++11 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not properly comparing the two strings, you are comparing the addresses of the two char arrays.

You have to use the strcmp function.

```
while(strcmp(str1,str2)!=0)
```

Or use the std::string class, which allows you to use the overloaded operator == in order to compare strings.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::string` instead of raw arrays and pointers, in order to avoid silly mistakes like opening up for buffer overflows, comparing pointers instead of strings, and so on.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
     std::string str1 = "abc123";
     std::string str2 = "abc123";
     do
     {
          std::cout << "String: ";
          std::cin >> str2;
     } while (str1 != str2);
     std::cout << "str1 is equal to str2.\n";
}
```

Comment: it almost feels like c++ should deprecate usage of char[] or char* for string and use std::string. what do you say mr Alf?

Comment: well, using char* would have gotten him a const warning.

Comment: I usually do that, I'm using chars now for another reason, normally I wouldn't. You forgot to return a value on your main function btw

Comment: @Koushik: IMHO there is no really good string class in C++11. It's not just that the interface is awkward, but neither `std::string` nor `std::wstring` works nicely in a portable way for international text. One solution is a new basic character encoding type that depends on the system, together with a corresponding string class. I've outlined the necessary type in an article in the Agusut 2013 issue of ACCU Overload Journal. I've not yet completed article about string class... ;-)

Comment: @yop: no, `main` is a very special function, that among other special properties has a default return value, namely 0.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf doesn't that depend on your compiler? I tried not returning a value on Visual C++ and the program works, but I always thought it was a bad practice to not do it.

Comment: @yop: no, it's guaranteed by the C++ standard (from C++98 and on).

Answer (score 2):

str1 and str2 are char arrays, which really means they are pointers to char arrays. Their values are constant, and will never be equal. Replace the declarations with:

```
 string str1 = "abc123";
 string str2 = "abc123";
```

and you will get better results.  (but will need  header)

Comment: of course, since this code looks more like C than C++, perhaps one of the strcmp answers is more suited?

Comment: Use of `cin` and `cout` smacks of C++ to me. ;-]

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the pointers.

Use `strcmp` rather.

Moreover, using `cin` is unsafe as left may be too small.

Modify as

```
} while(strcmp(str1, str2))
```

Answer (score -1):

In the main function stack frame when you are allocating two array:

The two arrays get two different fixed addresses which never changes !

Even if the contents of the array are changed everytime !

```
char str1[] = "abc123";  // str1 gets an unique fixed address  say 1000
char str2[] = "abc123";  // str2 gets an unique fixed address  say 1007
```

Thus the statement`while (str1 != str2);` keeps on comparing the address 1000 and 1007 and

thus the loop condition becomes true all the time .

Comment: It is exactly opposite of what you say.

Comment: **The address of the str1 and str2 are same** They are different (not same) hence forever loop.

Comment: I think you mean the condition is always false. My program was looping the whole time because it was checking if the addresses were the same, which they weren't, but then the ! made the condition return the opposite (always true)

Comment: I hope now my answer is clear. And in the former answer I wrote the same thing in short which was not clear.